# Override tab to open a visualforce page?

Tags: tab, visualforce

I have a custom tab . What I want to do is : when I click on that tab, it should open a VF page that I made. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to solve the situation.

I went to my custom object's tab, on the " Buttons, Links and Actions".
I went to the tab line and clicked "Edit". And from there, I was able to override the standard page.

Note : The page used when overriding a tab shouldn't use a standard controller.

Comment: You should probably mark this as the solution then.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days to do that, but I will. Maybe someone else will find it helpfull

Answer (score 5):

If you want the contents of the tab to be the VisualForce page, you need to make a VisualForce tab, not a Custom tab. In setup, VF tabs are at the bottom of the Tabs page where Custom tabs are at the top. I'm pretty sure you can't turn an existing tab from Custom to VF.

According to the [Creating Visualforce Tabs documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_tabs_create.htm&language=en_US).

> User Permissions Needed 
>   To create Visualforce Tabs: “Customize Application”
>
> You can build Visualforce tabs so that users can access Visualforce pages from within Salesforce.
>
> To create a Visualforce tab:
>
> 1. From Setup, click **Create | Tabs**.
> 2. Click **New** in the Visualforce Tabs related list.
> 3. Select the Visualforce page to display in the custom tab. If you have not already created the Visualforce page, click **Create a new page now**.

...and then there are several other fields to fill in on the UI.

Comment: I saw this part of the documentation, but there is no option for "create a page now".

Comment: Looks like you're right about that. I've never previously tried to create a VF Tab for a page that I hadn't created yet. So why not make the VF page first, and then select it in the "VisualForce Page" dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Go to setup->QuickSearch search for visualforce tab -> Click it inside -> It asks you the visualforce page you want to enter -> Choose from drop down list -> save it -> open the tab-> magic happens